# Not Getting Azure DevOps Code Coverage Information From Azure DevOps Services REST APIs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I have been able to generate **Angular 4** code coverage in azure devops build pipeline.

[Screenshot Of Generated Code Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf6kF.png)

[image]

[Screenshot Of Code Coverage Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Ho7.png)

But now I want to get the build coverage details from Azure DevOps Services REST APIs.

I am calling the REST API

> `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/codecoverage?buildId={buildId}&flags={flags}&api-version=5.1-preview.1`

of my azure build, as mentioned in

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1.

But everytime I am getting `{"value":[],"count":0}` as response.

I need to get the coverage information from Azure DevOps Services REST API so that it can be appended in Email. Looking for help in this regard from this forum.

Comment: I found a workaround, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75454440/193634. I know I am not answering your question, but hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `flags` parameter and make the url like this to check if the response body is your expected.

```
https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/test/codecoverage?buildId={buildId}&api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

In addition, if you just want to append it in Email, you can use Publish code coverage results Task to get the codecoverage artifact and append this in Email. More detailed in formation about this task, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, Frank. By removing the flags parameter, I am getting the result for branch coverage and line coverage. 

Is there any other api which can give more information on code coverage?

Comment: Also the branch coverage that I am getting via this api is different from what is displayed in the build pipeline code coverage tab (screenshot updated in the question), but the line coverage is correct, any idea about this issue @Frank Wang-MSFT. ***Response Snippet*** -> *"coverageData":[ { "coverageStats":[ { "label":"Branches", "position":6, "total":9844, "covered":6179, "isDeltaAvailable":false, "delta":0.0 },*

Comment: If you use Network tool to get the data, did the response data different from the data in the UI webpage? Like this.https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3N3f.png

Comment: Yes, Frank. The response data in network tool differs from what is there in UI, but only in case of branch coverage. In case of line coverage, the data is same, both in response and in UI.

Comment: @Shubho, If convenience, could you please share a simple sample of your code about the branch test in onedrive? Then I can test it on my side and try to find a way to resolve it.

Comment: Actually, I am implementing this on my organization's build pipeline. So it's not possible to share the code. I will try the same process on a sample project and see whether I face the same problem or not. If I face the same problem, then I will get back to you with the sample code that I experiment on.