# How to use Azure DevOps Rest API to get code coverage details

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to use "[Code Coverage - Get Build Code Coverage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" REST API, to get the code coverage details of my build:
[image]

When I use the api and do not specify any 'flags' values', I only get the summary information.

And when I add `flags=7` or `flags=2` or `flags=4`, I only get

```
{
  "value": [],
  "count": 0
}
```

My question is how can I get the coverage details of my build using REST API?

Answer (score 4):

You can delete the `flags` parameter and make the url like this to check if the response body is your expected.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/codecoverage?buildId={buildId}&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

As test result:

If we use the task `Visual Studio Test` and enable the option Code coverage enabled, we could see the `Download code coverage results` link and get the result as shown in the REST API [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/code%20coverage/get%20build%20code%20coverage?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#examples)

[image]

If we use the task Publish code coverage results, we could see the result in the UI, but cannot get response body via REST API.

[image]

**Update1**

According to the [product team's response](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/666414/view.html): Azure devops only support the download link for .coverage files currently. So we could not use this API to get the UI coverage report details

**Update2**

If you are using classic editor mode to create pipeline, we could see the option `Code coverage enabled`, check the pic below.

[image]

If you are using YAML mode to create pipeline, the field is `codeCoverageEnabled`, we need to add the code `codeCoverageEnabled: true`

Comment: Thanks. How can I create .coverage file? From Visual Studio Test task document, I don't see how to create a .coverage file.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops

Comment: Hi @sacheu, I have updated the answer, please check the update2

Comment: Hi @sacheu, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. I have tried adding codeCoverageEnabled to my yaml file, but that does not solve this issue. And I have decided not to use ado rest api to get the information.

Comment: Hi @sacheu, Would you mind sharing the final way to get code coverage details as the answer? It could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Comment: @VitoLiu I just found a workaround, I read the generated Summary.json instead of calling the API, much simpler. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a different approach to get the coverage details.

Initially I tried getting the code coverage details by calling the Azure DevOps REST API too, but it gets too complicated since the API is password protected therefore I need to set personal access token (PAT), this PAT has expiry, so I want to avoid this complication.

Instead of calling the api, I realized that the coverage details are in the generated `Cobertura.xml` or `Summary.json`, so there's no need to call the API.

Here is a sample yaml pipeline code (the relevant part):

```yaml
... build your code here, then...

          - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
            displayName: 'Run functional tests'
            inputs:
              command: 'test'
              projects: '**/*FunctionalTests.csproj'
              arguments: '-c $(buildConfiguration) --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --settings $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/coverlet.runsettings.xml'    
          - task: reportgenerator@5 # https://josh-ops.com/posts/azure-devops-code-coverage/
            displayName: 'Generate code coverage report'
            inputs:
              reports: '$(Agent.WorkFolder)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml'
              targetdir: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults'
              reporttypes: 'HtmlInline_AzurePipelines_Dark;Cobertura;JsonSummary'
          - task: PowerShell@2
            displayName: 'Check code coverage'
            condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                $jsonSummary = Get-Content -Raw $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/CoverageResults/Summary.json | ConvertFrom-Json
                $codeCoverage = $jsonSummary.summary.linecoverage
                Write-Host "Code coverage: $codeCoverage%"
                if ($codeCoverage -lt 80)
                {
                    Write-Error "Code coverage is below 80%. Current coverage: $codeCoverage%"
                    Exit 1
                }
                else
                {
                    Write-Host "Code coverage meets/exceeds 80%. Current coverage: $codeCoverage%" -ForegroundColor Green
                }

..the rest of your pipeline code...
```

What's important is to set `JsonSummary` in `reporttypes`, then we can load that json and check the `linecoverage`. Here the pipeline will spit an error if the line coverage is less than 80%.