# Azure DevOps - Comparing Code Coverage Against Different Branches

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, code-coverage

In Azure DevOps, is there a way to create a status check for a build pipeline for branch A, that compares the code coverage of branch B to A?

**e.g.** When creating a PR to merge branch B to A, the status check will approve the PR if branch B's code coverage is greater or equal to branch A's code coverage.

---

According to this [resource](https://www.benday.com/2023/01/10/enforce-code-coverage-as-part-of-pull-requests-in-azure-devops/#:%7E:text=The%20way%20to%20fix%20this%20is%20to%20add,on.%20coverage%3A%20status%3A%20comments%3A%20on%20diff%3A%20target%3A%2080%25) it is possible to set a hard limit on the files, but I'd like a more flexible code coverage check that compares the incoming branch to the destination branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't a default feature in Azure DevOps can meet your needs "When creating a PR to merge branch B to A, the status check will approve the PR if branch B's code coverage is greater or equal to branch A's code coverage." If you want such a feature, you could submit a feature request on:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.

You may also consider developing a custom extension to implement your needs. See [Custom actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pull-request-status?view=azure-devops#custom-actions) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ziyang Liu-MSFT! Do you think it is also possible to run code-coverage for both branch A and B and compare them in the YAML file that defines the pipeline? (If so, this case would not be able to generate a warning, but a strick pass/fail for the pipeline?)

Comment: I am not sure whether it's possible. Maybe you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679018/how-to-use-azure-devops-rest-api-to-get-code-coverage-details) to get code-coverage data of each branch's build and then compare them by custom scripts. If my answer above is helpful for you, in order to let others who have the similar question with you know this answer more clearly, it's suggested that you accept it according to [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Thanks!